# SQLite performance tuning on Windows IoT

Tags: sqlite, csv, database-performance, data-export, windows-iot-core-10

I have a windows IoT Application which is capturing data from some data source and storing it on persistent storage. Here is my technology stack

1. Windows 10 IoT Core
2. UWP Background application (C#)
3. SQLite
4. SQLite for Universal Windows Platform 3.19.3
5. SQLite.NET-PCL NuGet https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

and I am using Raspberry Pi 3 for testing this solution. For storing the data I have decided to use SQLite. Following is the schema of table

```
public class tblDataLog
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }

    public int? Param1 { get; set; }

    public int? Param2 { get; set; }

    public double? Param2 { get; set; }

    public double? Param4 { get; set; }

    public double? Param5 { get; set; }

    public int? Param6 { get; set; }

    public int? Param7 { get; set; }

    public double? Param7 { get; set; }

    public double? Param8 { get; set; }
    public double? Param9 { get; set; }
    public double? Param10 { get; set; }
    public double? Param11 { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public DateTime RecordedOn { get; set; }
}
```

For testing I have stored 2 million rows in this table and there is no insertion is being performed. Following is my code to fetch the data for last 6 hours

```
var commandstr = $"select * from tblDataLog Where RecordedOn >= " + DateTime.Now.AddHours(-6) + " AND RecordedOn <= " + DateTime.Now;
var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand(commandstr);
var sensorDataQuery = cmd.ExecuteQuery<tblDataLog>(); //This line takes around 90 seconds on average to complete
```

The problem is that for only six hours of data (roughly 216000 rows, data rate is 10Hz) it is taking around 90 seconds to fetch records which is too slow. At the end I need to convert the data to CSV and provide a file download, I have tried to store the file as a flat csv file which is exponentially fast as compared to SQLite approach, like for the above case it is only taking 5 seconds on average.

I want to know what options do I have to optimize the SQLite performance (If any)? It is very simple query, I doubt that it is due to SD card storage, I am using class 10 storage card, and CSV is also working on same card with reasonable speed.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up the `DateTime` search a little bit by making this table a [WITHOUT ROWID table](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) with `DateTime` as the primary key.

But reading and parsing tens of megabytes of data from the database and constructing hundreds of thousands of `tblDataLog` objects in memory will take time.
You should not use those objects when you do not actually need them; reading the data with a different kind of API (e.g., SQLitePCL.raw) would be more efficient.